# Check randomness of XID field in DHCP request

Tags: security, testing, request, dhcp, nmap

I want to test my UUT by sending DHCP request from it and check if the xid the request packet is random.
Also I need to test if my UUT drops response that have invalid xid field. is there any tool available for it?
I used nmap to run dhcp discover. but not sure how to send invalid xid inorder to check if UUT drops it.

Answer (score 0):

In nmap you should use a script to this.

You may use the example broadcast-dhcp-discover script and customize to change the xid
https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/scripts/broadcast-dhcp-discover.nse

Then you will run it with the command

```
nmap --script script-name -e $INTERFACE
```